# How to set custom paper size for print in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, printing

I have 100+ reports in a MS Access file. I need to set a custom paper size for print for all/selected reports. One obvious way is to go to each and every report and set the print paper size. Is there more convenient methods to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the page size using the Printer property of the report. This function will set the page size to A3. acPRPA3 is the Access constant for A3. There are a number of built in constants for different page sizes.

```
Dim rpt As Report

Set rpt = Reports(<MyReportName>)

rpt.Printer.PaperSize = acPRPSA3
```

Your report will need to be open to run this function.

Comment: Great answer and might I add, you can loop through [all reports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194322.aspx) iteratively opening each one and running your above code. The OP probably would not want to open each of the 100+ reports each time to run your function.